# android how to wrap spinner drop down text (android 4)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have a `Spinner` where the text both inside the spinner and the choices when the spinner is expanded (drop down view) can be quite long depending on the locale. i set a custom view for both the spinner view and the drop down view that should allow the text lines to wrap,

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

and in the code,

```
    spinnerPermission = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.permission_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> permissionAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.add_share_dialog_permissions,
        R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);
    permissionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerPermission.setAdapter(permissionAdapter);
```

this works fine in android 2, but in android 4, the text in the drop down view still won't wrap,

[image]

although it's not clear from the image, the text in the spinner view does wrap correctly. I can't tell for sure, but it seems like the container around the drop down views is not constrained by the screen and expands off the screen to the right. That would prevent the text from wrapping, because as far as the `TextView` is concerned, there's plenty of space.

Here is the spinner's popup view in hierarchy viewer,

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean. is that a suggestion?

Comment: try setting the `layout_width` to an explicit value instead of `match_parent` for the dropdown view.

Comment: i'm not sure that's a reasonable approach, considering all of the possible screen sizes and orientations.

Comment: You could try examining your open `Spinner` in Hierarchy View and see if that tells you anything, such as confirming your "expands off the screen to the right" theory (which sounds plausible). I haven't tried viewing an open `Spinner` in Hierarchy View, so while I hope it'll work, it's possible that for some reason that is not possible.

Comment: nah,  german language is always so long, that is breaks boxes (design)

Comment: @CommonsWare i can see it in hierarchy viewer. i don't see any evidence that it expands off the screen though. looking at the "bounds", it seems to end at the screen width (720). i'll attach this to the post.

Comment: @toadzky setting an explicitly width just truncates the text and does not cause it to wrap. surprising.

Comment: I recently created a question with the same topic that already got some upvotes but no solution yet: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14139106/1018177

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by custom layout where I have TextView inside LinearLayout. Both TextView and LinearLayout have fixed width 200dp. Then it wraps the text correctly both on Android 2.3 and 4.0.

Comment: yes, that works, but i don't want to fix the width. if i do that, i have to consider the proper width against all sorts of different screens and orientations.

Answer (score 0):

`CheckedTextView` extends `TextView`, which has `inputType, maxLines, minLines` attributes.
Try applying `android:inputType="textMultiline"` attribute to your `CheckedTextView`, that should help.

Comment: that makes the spinner operate strangely (can't select the drop down views), and it still does not wrap. also, lint flags it saying inputType should only be used on editable text views.

Comment: also, even explicitly setting `lines="2"` has no effect.

Comment: try to add android:scrollHorizontally="false"

Answer (score 0):

Create custom layout, first Goto res folder->create New XML Layout file 
eg: simple_spinner_layout.xml

link:http://justpaste.it/edit/2866098/aab2f5f3

Its work for me.
Plz vote for this answer if u have satisfied.