# Old-fashioned Spinner for Holo theme

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Is it possible to have old-fashioned Spinner (the one where you are selecting values in popup window) on Holo theme? I don't need it to look like on older platforms, I need to select values in large popup window instead of drop-down list.

If not, do you know any already implemented control like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

API Demos is a sample application that can be optionally installed with your Android/Eclipse development environment. It's in the samples folder underneath the android-sdk folder (on a Windows PC, I don't know about other platforms). If it's not there then you can add it with the Android SDK Manager.

When running API Demos on your device, go down the lists as follows...

Views -> Animation -> Push

There's a spinner on that screen.

In the project code for API Demos, the source code for that spinner...

package: com.example.android.apis.view

source file: Animation2.java

Comment: As far as i saw in example, the whole screen is shownig in classic theme. And i need all in Holo and just one spinner in classic theme.

Comment: You're using an older version of API Demos. A later one will give you Holo theme. I think I understand your question now, though. You want to keep the radio buttons in the spinner?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep spinner items with radiobuttons in "popup window"

Comment: Hmmm. You had me curious. I tried modifying the XML for the spinner in API Demos that I referenced above. No matter what I tried, the spinner held on to the Holo theme. Perhaps a solution exists if you take bits from this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14392369/1620738

Comment: thank you, I'll try. The way I should follow to implement such simple feature makes me mad.