# Holo spinner's dropdown can't wrap text?

Tags: android, spinner

Whatever layout I use for my spinner's

```
setDropDownViewResource()
```

it always cuts off the text at the right edge.

```
android:singleLine(false)
```

doesn't seem to work in the dropdown of Holo spinner's.
When I initiate the spinner with old dialog mode

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, SPINNER.DIALOG_MODE);
```

then the text wrapping works fine.

Why does the text not wrap in the Holo spinner dropdown?

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, SPINNER.MODE_DROPDOWN);
```

Comment: Did you try using a custom text layout for the spinner layout?text wrapping can be achieved there

Answer (score 0):

In `holo theme spinner` by default uses `dropdown mode`. And all moves with overriding default styles just move to switching `spinner mode` to `dialog mode` which succesfully wraps multiline text as in api 11.

***Solutions can be:***

**1)** *You can manually wrap listview in PopupWindow and show it under TextView on click and hide it on listItem click.*

**2)** *Override getDropDownView method in ArrayAdapter and put setSingleLine(false) in post method  of view. So when view completly created it wraps the text to appropriate lines.*

Here is the explanation in [spinner-does-not-wrap-text-is-this-an-android-bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139106/spinner-does-not-wrap-text-is-this-an-android-bug).