# Android Spinner not work multiline

Tags: android, spinner, multiline

I have a problem when viewing spinner in android. that is multiline
Android 5.1.1 is not displayed .. but below android if the multiline is
the code I use is the following.

This same code right out of another question but did not see answer to help me

/res/values/arrays.xml:

```
<string-array name="items">
<item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt.</item>
<item>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.</item>
```

res/layout/spinner_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

Set Adapter

```
spinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.items,
            R.layout.spinner_item));
```

please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override getDropDownView method in ArrayAdapter and put setSingleLine(false) in post method of view. So when view completly created it wraps the text to appropriate lines.

```
@Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new TextView(_context);
        }

        TextView item = (TextView) convertView;
        item.setText("asddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
        final TextView finalItem = item;
        item.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finalItem.setSingleLine(false);
            }
        });
        return item;
    }
```

[For details visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139106/spinner-does-not-wrap-text-is-this-an-android-bug)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason why `setSingleLine(false)` needs to be called in the post method?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerFrom"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: not working tested in android 10